# Is it possible to earn Imperial Bux as a tip for elevator rides?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

At one point I read that sometimes bitizens will tip you with Imp. Bux after delivering them to their desired floor, can anyone confirm this please?

Answer (score 3):

It is exceedingly rare, but I have gotten a tip of 1 Bux for an elevator ride.  I have 68 levels, and I think it may have happened one time.

I stole this from the Tiny Death Star Wiki -

[image: Tip Bux]

Comment: I just got tipped a bux with an up-to-date version (iOS). So, it does happen, but would seem to be very rare.

Answer (score 0):

This was a feature of Tiny Tower.  In Tiny DeathStar, bitizens do not tip bux.  They can however spark a buying frenzy.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Stocking a floor definitely does...not sure I've seen it in response to a shopper.